# IIS Case insensitive Virtual Directory(App) issue

Tags: iis-8.5, virtual-directory, case-insensitive

I have an app in IIS whose url is "http://localhost/MAIN", please note the uppercase virtual directory.

When I try to access this url with a lower case app/virtual directory name, like "http://localhost/main" then the app turns the url into "http://localhost/MAIN/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fmain" note the "%2fmain". Upon performing a login, I get redirected back to the login page/route.

I think IIS should return a 404 for lower case virtual directory name.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: IIS is case insensitive regarding virtual directories and file paths.  /MAIN and /main are the same.  Just like INDEX.HTM and index.htm are the same.  In your case I guess MVC is just being "smart" (take that as you will).

Answer (score 1):

have had same problem

Change strpos for stripos in function getUrlencodedPrefix located at vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php.

We have had issues accessing our laravel application on IIS with fast-cgi.

The app url http://server/myApp points to the application public folder and 90% of the time it works, but for some reason after days of being OK it suddenly stops working with a route error [in RouteCollection.php (line 179)]. The only way to get access back through the same url but lowercase "A" http://server/myapp. After days it switches back to uppercase "A".

The issue became worst about 2 days ago when it started switching almost on an hourly bases.

We have traced back the issue to vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php line 2043 [strpos changing it to stripos] fixed the problem.

What seems to be the root cause is the handleing of fast-cgi with the _SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] variable. When the application pool recycles the php-cgi.exe process the first request to the process will set this variable to the Case Sensative portion of the virtual folder. From then on matchAgainstRoutes (vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php) will fail as the case will not match.

I am looking for a long term solution, as any update at Symphony Core or Laravel will most probably change this FIX back. I hope in the meantime this post will help.